# difference between #define and enum{} in C

Tags: c, enums, preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Enum and Define Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136946/difference-between-enum-and-define-statements)

when should one use

```
enum {BUFFER = 1234};
```

over

```
#define BUFFER 1234
```

?

what are the advantages `enum` brings compared to `#define`? i know, that `#define` is just simple text substitution and `enum` names the constant somehow. but why would one need that at all?