# Choosing between enum or define in C?

Tags: c, enums, casting

I noticed that most of the predefined values in `libc` are written using `#define` directives. For example, the `whence` parameter takes an `int` in `fseek` where (from my knowledge) an `enum` would have been better. There are plenty of examples like this that should obviously exist for a reason (other than back-compatibility issues).

So I am wondering in which case is it better to use `#define` whereas `enum` is a [type-safe alternative more easily discoverable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136954/2612235).

As a practical example consider a `typedef` representing an input/output channel, as it could be the case on the kernel. The gpio can be configured either in input or output. Is it worth to use an `enum` directive here?

```
typedef struct gpio {
    size_t port; 
    size_t bit;
    enum { DIR_INPUT, DIR_OUTPUT } direction; // or `bool`?
    bool value;
} gpio;
```

Notice that the `enum` can be implemented in three different manners:

i) Type:

```
typedef enum gpio_direction {   
   DIR_OUTPUT
   DIR_INPUT
} gpio_direction;
```

ii) Global enum

```
enum gpio_direction {   
   DIR_OUTPUT
   DIR_INPUT
} gpio_direction;
```

iii) Anonymous enum (as showed in my example).

Comment: one problem with `enum` is that enumerators always have type `int`. They can't be used for values outside the range of `int`.  Another potential problem in your code is that the enum size may vary between compilers (or even compilations, in theory) , messing with your struct layout.

Comment: I personally would use always a Enum when the value doesn't matter like in state machines or in conditon fields. In this cases I never compare ENUM with int. I always compare ENUM with ENUM. In cases where the actual value matters I would always use #defines. E.G. Hardware configuration register values or Bit fields.

Comment: You are asking what is best practice in embedded systems. libc was written by desktop programmers. There are more things to consider for embedded systems, where it is far more important to be explicit with types. If you aren't asking about embedded systems specifically, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum) is the duplicate. Overall this topic has been debated endlessly all over SO, you can find plenty of info about it.

Comment: Your latter suggestion is slightly better since you don't really use `fseek` on an embedded device, but again I don't agree with your choice. I am asking about `Why is it better to use enum where `libc` uses #defines for most cases`. I can rename the question if you want to.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to re-open the question just to close it with a different duplicate. If there's a consensus that this post isn't a duplicate of [“static const” vs “#define” vs “enum”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum), then it will get re-opened. I think it is a duplicate.

Comment: The interesting (and non-duplicate) part of the question is: why then  is `#define` used so often?

Comment: I can't do that, since I am the person who closed the post. If I re-open a question, I will not be able to close vote on it.

Comment: @HansLub The answer to that is likely mostly subjective though. Unless someone can drag up the coding standard used for libc.

Comment: @HansLub that's a matter of opinion really. I guess some coders don't realize enum is usable for this purpose. Another consideration might be that defines can be used for conditional inclusion but enums can't

Comment: @M.M `enum` type detail: [What is the size of an enum in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/366017/2410359)

Comment: With `enum`, code is quieter.  with `#define`, CODE IS SHOUTING.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There are plenty of examples like this that should obviously exist for
>   a reason

One reason is that there is no portable way to refer to a C `enum` from assembly code. Low-level code usually was (and often still is) written in assembly, so constants used by that low-level code will be specified by a  `#define` rather than with `enum`.

Another reason is the idiom `if (verbosity & WAKE_THE_NEIGHBOURS)` where a `#defined` value is used to specify a bit position.

> So I am wondering in which case is it better to use #define whereas
>   enum is a type-safe alternative more easily discoverable

In all other cases I would (today - using `#define` is also somewhat of a tradition) use an `enum`, so that `if (verbosity == RED)` will provoke a warning (if you use e.g. `gcc` with `-Wall`).

Comment: Well, is it also possible to use `#ifndef _LANGUAGE_ASM \n enum {...} \n #else \n #define ... \n #endif`

Comment: The `if (verbosity & WAKE_THE_NEIGHBOURS)` is a very good point

Comment: `if (verbosity & WAKE_THE_NEIGHBOURS)` could as well be used with an enum though... except you will get a signed type. Sloppily written `#define`  will do the same, so there's no real difference, unless the  `#define` is written with care.

Comment: @Lundin: no, `WAKE_THE_NEIGHBOURS` needs a value from the sequence `1,2,4,8,16,..`, while an `enum`  will allocate `0,1,2,3,..`. You can get around that with `<<` but what's the point?

Comment: @HansLub Nothing prevents you from giving any value to an enum. `typedef enum { WAKE_THE_NEIGHBOURS = 16; .. } wake_t`. This is why your answer doesn't make much sense, as it currently stands.

Comment: Yes, but you also lose the (rather weak) type-safety: `if (verbosity & RED)` will be just as (il)legitimate as `if (verbosity & WAKE_THE_NEIGHBOURS)` : both need to convert an `enum` to an int, erasing all information about the original `enum` type

Answer (score 3):

While one probably should use other solutions where such are available there are still situations where macros are required. Some are historical reasons, but there are also reasons valid still today.

For example you mention the `whence` argument to `fseek` (ie `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR` and `SEEK_END). These are (for historical reasons) specified to be macros in the standard - so the implementor has to define them as macros to be fully compliant, some evil programmer could write (and blame the library for consequences):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef SEEK_CUR
int evil = *(int*)0;
#endif
```

But as far as I can see theres no reason why they couldn't write:

```
enum __WHENCE_T {
    __SEEK_CUR,
    __SEEK_END,
    __SEEK_SET
};

#define SEEK_CUR __SEEK_CUR
#define SEEK_END __SEEK_END
#define SEEK_SET __SEEK_SET
```

Another historical reason is that the compiler might have produced more efficient code when using macros. Code that were written back then might still be around and containing constructs that worked better back then (and still works pretty god today).

Modern reasons are if you need to use the values outside of the C-compiler. For example as mentioned if you want to use the value in assembler code (or some other language). All you need to do is to make sure that the header doesn't expand to something (that contain C code) unless it's compiled with a C compiler. For example:

```
#define NUMBER 42

#ifdef __STDC__
extern int variable;

int function(void);
#endif
```

if included from assembler the macro `NUMBER` would still be expandable (and expand to the same thing as for C programs).