# Compile-time assignment of consecutive numbers to #defines

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I have a series of #defines that I want assigned consecutive numbers
at compile time so I can refer to them later and know their order.
Currently, I'm assigning a number to each #define in order,
but, if I change the order, I have to renumber the #defines.

```
#define THING_A     1 // I'm doing this now...
#define THING_F     2
#define THING_C     3
#define THING_B     4
```

Not shown: these #define are between array elements and refer to
the element order.  I often need to rearrange the element order.
If I reorder them, as below, I want their numbers to change accordingly
without me having to go through and edit the numbers like this:

```
#define THING_C     1
#define THING_A     2
#define THING_B     3
#define THING_F     4
```

What can I replace the numbers with (the same for
every #define) that will result in consecutive assignments?
I can't use "__COUNTER_" like this...

```
#define THING_B     (__COUNTER__)
```

... because every time I use the defined value later, it gets larger.
What is this "(something)"?

```
#define THING_A     (something)
#define THING_B     (something)
#define THING_C     (something)
#define THING_D     (something)
```

Comment: What about an enumeration instead of #define? The values of the enum will get values in order.

Comment: The essence of what you're trying to do here is to have macros expand according to the order you define the macros in.  That, fundamentally, is impossible; expansion of a macro invocation is entirely a function of _which_ macros are defined at the time of invocation, and _what_ they are defined as.  The order in which they were defined plays no role whatsoever.  Now you could chain the definitions, which defeats the point; auto-increments like counter's won't work because they're invocation features not definition ones.  The best thing is to just use enum's like @rmaddy suggests.

Comment: Thank you.  I have found a way to use an enum as you both suggest, a la https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035640/236415 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035640/236415 for how to use an enum as suggested by the commenters.